# chart js label placement

Tags: javascript, charts

Thanks for the help in advance.I'm implementing chart js but i'm facing issue in getting the correct size of the chart and in the placement of labels.Can anyone help me with this The first image is my desired output [image: Desired Output]

[image: Output from my code]

Comment: The code is used  : https://codepen.io/ANANTHUC/pen/vYZEgOj

Comment: Pro tip: you can add your code to the post as a runnable snippet instead of linking the codepen in the comments